# How to make the search engine use search api db?

Tags: search

I have installed search_api, with search_api_db, create 2 indexes, one for node, one for users. 
The conf:

- server: search_db server,
- 2 indexes: default_node_index and user_index
- service class: database service

The one for users has parameters:

- field: email (fulltext)
- filter:role (limit to one only).

The index seems working good, it indexes the right number of users, I checked the uids in the db and it is corresponding to the good users. 
But still when I use the search (search/user/something), the search is on the names instead of emails, and the role filter is not applied. So in short, it is not using the search_api_db. It looks like the whole system is overriden by some other fulltext on everything search. I'm stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ok I found out what is my problem. 
I miss the other entity necessary to build to use the search api db: the search page using the [search page module](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_page) or views, instead of the system search page.

There is a tutorial here to have a more accurate and complete picture of the process: http://webwash.net/tutorials/intro-search-api-part-1-how-create-search-pages